# Adding image src path in cakephp

Tags: html, cakephp, hyperlink

Iam creating an image link in cakephp using html tag, i have a problem with adding src path.

I tried

```
<a href="#today1" id="lnk3">
 <img  src="/iserprofiles/app/webroot/img/todaysallocation.png">Todays Allocation</a>
```

but image is not loaded. if anybody know please reply. i know that we can also create image link using cakephp, but i faced one problem

i u sed this code

```
  <?php echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image('todaysallocation.png',
  array('width' => '200', 'height' => '45')) ,
                   '#today',array('escape' => false));?>
```

i dont want to use any controller or action as url, simply i just added  '#today',
but my problem is i need to add one id for this. how can we done this????

Comment: I recommend using a proper virtual host setup for your local environent ( http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/05/29/working-with-domains-locally/ ). Then your `Html->image('todaysallocation.png')` will result in a proper src path `/img/todaysallocation.png` which then will also work properly once you deploy to the live server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in Your browser patch: `localhost/iserprofiles/app/webroot/img/todaysallocation.png`
, but i think the problem is in Your .htaccess file, because path to image will look like `localhost/iserprofiles/img/todaysallocation.png`

Comment: when i try to access localhost/iserprofiles/app/webroot/img/todaysallocation.png it shows object not found

Comment: I think that, check 2nd path

Comment: sorry when i change iserprofiles to my project folder name, it shows the image, before i given the controller name..now im getting..but my doubt is this is in local host, but when i host this, is there any problem with this link???

Comment: What kind of server You have on localhost?